How to show pretty undercurl in Neovim in tmux?
steps to reproduce:

open new iTerm2 window (no Tmux)
run

echo "rong;" | nvim --clean +"set spell" -


notice the word is underlined with a curly line



open new tmux pane
repeat step 2
notice "rong" is underlined with a normal line


Note: Tmux is capable of displaying the pretty undercurl:

my tmux config:
set-option -s default-terminal 'tmux-256color'

set-option -sa terminal-overrides ',xterm-256color:RGB'

How do I make Neovim show the pretty underline when in Tmux?

You can manually set the right t_ options, or configure your terminfo database/TERM environment variable. That should help.

How would changing my TERM help?  I get the same behavior when running echo "rong" | TERM=xterm-256color nvim --clean +"set spell" -.  This command shows the squigly outside of tmux and a solid underline in tmux

Would you please give me more details about "setting the right t_ options" and configuring my terminfo database?

See for example :help terminal-options and where I make tmux in alacritty support certain codes

By "pretty" one, I assume you mean the far-uglier-looking curly line, as opposed to the very-pretty-looking straight line
